# Not having an argument shuts off my discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

If I don't define a person to ban, it shuts my bot off.

ERROR: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined`

```js
if (msg.member.roles.cache.has()) {
 let user = msg.mentions.members.first();
 msg.channel.send(`│ Banned @${user.displayName}!`);
 user.ban();
}
```

Comment: Its simple javascript

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if you don't give a mention, then it will generate an error and the bot will crash.
You should make a return statement where you prevent this from happening.

```js
if (msg.member.roles.cache.has('BAN_MEMBERS')) {
 let member = msg.mentions.members.first();
 // prevents from not mentionning
 if (!member) return msg.channel.send(`Give a user to ban !`);
 // If the code continues, then there is a mention
 try {
  user.ban();
  msg.channel.send(`│ Banned @${member.user.displayName}!`);
 } catch (err) {
  msg.channel.send('I cannot ban this member !');
 }
} else msg.channel.send('You do not have the permission to do this');
```

So I fixed many problems :

- First, if you want the name of a `member` you'll have to use the user object. So you can't use `member.displayName` but `member.user.username`
- Second, you need to prevent that if the bot can't ban the member. If for example, the member is an administrator or the owner of the server
- Last, what you asked for, if there is no mention in the message, it will send a message telling you that you didn't pass a member to ban

I suggest you check out some tutorials like the [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/adding-more-commands.html)

Comment: i changed it a little bit better, if you still have an error please copy past the error message here so i know what exactly is the problem ^^

Comment: It replys with __**You do not have permission to do this**__, even tho i have the ban members permision..

Comment: then you don't have the permission to ban members in the server.

Comment: I do, the member has no roles.

Comment: check [https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html)